# SQL Concatenate View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to create a view to concatanate a number of lines into a single line.

The table in question is QotMaster, and I need to join all lines from the NComment field where LineType = '6' and im guessing to group them under each quote to group by the Quote field.  Each of the lines to concatenate has the field Line and starts at 2 and increases depending on how many lines there are to the quotes comment.

Ultimately i'd like a single line to read:

```
Quote           NComment
00202300        Lines for quotes all listed one after the other starting at 2 and so on
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated.  Ive tried to dump a section I need concatenating below.

```
Quote   Line    LineType    DefaultEntry    ProductClass    TaxCode FedSalesTax MStockCode  MDescription    MWarehouse  MUom    MDecimals   MLineShipDate   MCusStockCode   MCusRetailPrice MMass   MVolume MUserField1 NComment    NCommentFromLin NCommentType    NCommentTextTyp NSrvIncTotal    NSrvSummary NSrvChargeType  NSrvParentLine  NSrvQtyFactor   NSrvApplyFactor NSrvDecimalRnd  NSrvDecRndFlag  NSrvMinValue    NSrvMaxValue    NSrvMulDiv  NPrtOnInv   NPrtOnDel   NPrtOnAck   NPrtOnQuote NCommentFlag1   NCommentFlag2   NCommentFlag3   NCommentFlag4   NCommentFlag5   NCommentFlag6   NCommentPoJob   TimeStamp   Version Release SalesOrderLine  MBomFlag    MParentKitType  MQtyPer MScrapPercentage    MPrintComponent MComponentSeq   MOptionalFlag   Estimate    ConfirmedFlag
00202300    1   7   0   M20             002023000000001                 Periodic inspection & test      **      0   2012-01-13 00:00:00.000                                 0.00000 0.000000    0.000000                                                            0                       0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                        0   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6EE          0           0.000000    0.00    N                            
00202300    2   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            Pre-Formed Windings, Sheffield                  0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C0          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    3   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            To carry out a periodic inspection and test     0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C1          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    4   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            of the fixed wiring installation.  This will    0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C2          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    5   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            consist of 100% inspection and 10% testing,     0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C3          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    6   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            based on previous records being available.      0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C4          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    7   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            The price is based on no serious defects        0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C5          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    8   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            being found, which may result in the testing    0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C6          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    9   6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            being expanded to cover 25%, which would        0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C7          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    10  6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            incur additional costs. A full report will      0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C8          0           0.000000    0.00                                 
00202300    11  6   0                                                                                           0   NULL                                    0.00000 0.000000    0.000000            be issued upon completion.                      0   N                   0   0.000000        0       0.00    0.00                    Y   1   0   0   0   0   0       0x000000002414E6C9          0           0.000000    0.00
```

Comment: so, what have you tried that does not work? Or are you expecting some one here to do it for you?

Comment: @ItayMoav Im not exactly a SQL expert as you can see, i was just after some advice on how to do it, on looking at how to concatenate lines i drew a blank.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Im not quite sure, where would I find this out? Im using MS SQL 2005.

Comment: That's what I want to know: `MS SQL 2005` RDBMS = Relational DataBase Management  System

Answer (score 0):

In sql server, you'd just need to create a function to do something along these lines:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[mergeComments](@quote NVARCHAR(8))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comment nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @delimiter nvarchar(2)

SET @delimiter = ', '
SET @comment = ''

SELECT @comment = @comment + ISNULL(NComment,'')+@delimiter
FROM QotMaster
WHERE Quote = @quote AND Line > 1

SET @comment = substring(@comment,1,len(@comment)-LEN(@delimiter))

RETURN @comment

END
```

Then your view would just have do something along the lines of

```
SELECT Quote, dbo.mergeComments(Quote) NQuote 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Quote FROM QotMaster)
```

That's just off the top of my head so there's probably a better way to do it.